# Why I got an error while trying to use Minikube as Docker Desktop on Windows?

Tags: docker, minikube

I have Windows.

I have tried to set up minikube as Docker Desktop and followed the instruction : https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/docker_desktop_replacement/

I do not see any errors in cmd.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --container-runtime=docker --vm=true
* minikube v1.28.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing hyperv VM for "minikube" ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.25.3 on Docker 20.10.20 ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
  - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

docker --version also works fine.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f
```

However when I try to do docker compose up I got an error: error during connect

```
d:\projects\ui-tests>docker compose up
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dui-tests%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can someone help with that?

UPD1:

I have run this command in cmd, but there was no output(do not know if it is ok):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Have you run the relevant `minikube docker-env` command to point Docker at the Minikube VM, the third section in the page you link to?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Yes, I have run this command in cmd, but there was no output(do not know if it is ok):
```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resole this problem. Rancher desktop was chosen instead

Answer (score 0):

The error might have been caused because you are using hyper-v based docker deployment or because of exporting the variables incorrectly. I tried a different approach and it worked for me.

1. Instead of using hyper-v I have used wsl2 for docker. First you need to
   install wsl refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) for more information.
2. Next you need to download docker engine binary files from the official
   docker site and make some configuration as mentioned in this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-server-and-client-binaries-on-windows).
3. Now you can install minikube for windows and select the [driver as
   docker](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/) now as docker path is accessible across the system docker-
   compose will work fine.

Hope this will help you in resolving your issues.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However it does not help